# Unable to find database in data/data/ in Android

Tags: java, android

I am using Android Development Kit, Eclipse. I created an application which creates a database. there are following problems:

- The application closes showing error.
- The Application do not creates any database.
- If there is any database I am not able to see it in **data/data** using DDMS.

What should I do.?

**How to see for the files stored in data/data**

**Why my database is not getting created. Is there something wrong?**

I used the tutorial by [Vogella](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html) made the same application. but dint work

Comment: Can you post logcat? Are you using an emulator or real device?

Comment: I am using real device. I am novice. Can you tell me how to post the logcat?

Comment: add here your java code would be nice...

Comment: In a real device you can see data via DDMS only if you root your device. For logcat, copy and paste you code and your logcat here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should run on emulator to check files and database via `DDMS`. Real device will not show data or files via `DDMS` due to security reasons.

If you root your device you will be able to see your database and files vai `DDMS`.

As for your errors, please share some code and tell the community where it went wrong

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a real device and it's not rooted then you won't be able to see the contents of the /data/data folder, as this is how android is design to protect sensible application data.

if you are using the emulator or a rooted device then you would be able to access this folder.

So maybe you DB is getting created you just can't access this folder to see it.

Comment: but if the database is created then why the application gets close automatically? When I open it. it says there is some error in the onCreate method.

Comment: Here is the [code](https://code.google.com/p/android-database-example/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fsrc%2Fcom%2Fexample)....

Comment: 1. you already accepted an answer that means that you figured the problem out and got a solution.
2. I asked for the logcat output.